# InflateException in android along with Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-layout, inflate-exception

I am getting InflateExcepetion error in my code following with Resource not found exception . I have followed up lots of thread for the similar kind of exception but all the solution seems provide the information of layout not inflating, Image size is too large or  sometime it cause because of OOM exception as well.
My error logs takes me to a code line where I am creating an object of a DialogBox.

below is the line of code where i am getting this exception class is **MySettingsDialog**.

```
dialog = new DialogView(context)
dialog.setContentPaddings(10, 10, 10, 10);
 dialog.setDialogWidth(450);
 dialog.setFirstButtonText(context.getString(R.string.button_apply));
 dialog.setSecondButtonText(context.getString(R.string.button_cancel));
 dialog.setThirdButtonText(null);
 dialog.showThirdButton(false);
 dialog.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.bo_settings_title));
```

**P.S> This exception doesn't come often its like I have to run a automation script to get this exception and crash.**

Below is the Logs I am attaching

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class <unknown>

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.init(DialogView.java:165)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.<init>(DialogView.java:81)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.<init>(DialogView.java:71)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.<init>(DialogView.java:63)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.pqr.def.qqq.SettingsDialog.<init>(SettingsDialog.java:100)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.pqr.def.qqq.MapViewData.BoSettings(MapViewData.java:8137)

    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.pqr.def.qqq.MapViewData.access$41700(MapViewData.java:163)
    03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   ... 23 more

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020145

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1118)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:693)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at android.widget.CompoundButton.setButtonDrawable(CompoundButton.java:185)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.android.widget.control.CheckBox.init(CheckBox.java:39)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   at com.abc.android.widget.control.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:28)

03-13 16:37:38.742 W/LoggingEvent( 1798):   ... 26 more
    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798): *** UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION IN THREAD Thread[main,5,main] ***

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class <unknown>

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.init(DialogView.java:165)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.<init>(DialogView.java:81)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.<init>(DialogView.java:71)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at com.abc.android.dialog.DialogView.<init>(DialogView.java:63)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at com.abc.pqr.def.qqq.SettingsDialog.<init>(MySettingsDialog.java:100)

    03-13 16:37:38.744 E/WindowsManagerApplication( 1798):  at com.abc.pf.map.data.MyMap.checkUIForBoSettings(MyMap.java:8137)
```

DialogView.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogRoot"
    android:layout_width="336dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_window_expand_bkg"
    android:minHeight="233dp"
    android:minWidth="336dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTopBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_dialog" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleIcon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.abcDialog.Small.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/titleIcon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close"
            style="@style/CloseStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="162dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_area_dialog"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="12dp" >

        <com.abc.android.widget.control.CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/bottom_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFifth"
            style="@style/ButtonSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:minWidth="78dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Fifth"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFourth"
            style="@style/ButtonSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:minWidth="78dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Fourth"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btThird"
            style="@style/ButtonSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:minWidth="78dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Third" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btSecond"
            style="@style/ButtonSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:minWidth="78dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Second" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFirst"
            style="@style/ButtonSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:minWidth="78dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="First" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why you are setting `null` text in  `dialog.setThirdButtonText(null);`

Comment: Do you think this can lead to the inflate exception ?

Comment: its not a `inflate exception` its a `Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: Post your *layout* code as well please.

Comment: Yes as I edited my question this exception doesn't come all the time its a hard one to pop up so if I remove the null will this solve the issue ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ posted

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox on your layout file which has a wrong reference as its drawable.

Comment: Can you explain it in little more extensive way ? Do you mean to say I am referring checkbox as a drawable ?

Comment: To do that, I need you to update your question and add your layout xml as well.

Comment: Layout xml contain lots of sensitive information regarding the client and to hide that i have to edit the whole XML file. Anyways I am following up your leads too.

Comment: Then I don't think that I be able to help you more without details.